# Sourcemap between compiled, minified and concatenated css file and sass files

Tags: css, sass, gulp, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

I have following task which compiles *.scss files to scc, minifies them and concatenates to one css file.

```
gulp.task("scss-to-css", ["clean-css"], function () {
return gulp.src(pathToScssFiles)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(minifyCss({}))
    .pipe(concat("app.min.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(contentDir));
});
```

Is it possible to add sourcemap from app.min.css to *.scss files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend for using the `gulp-ruby-sass` module instead of `gulp-sass`.
When I tried to make source map like you, I failed to get the source map of original each scss file. So I'm looking for other way, the below gulpfile code seemed to be better.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
//var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');


gulp.task('scss-to-css', function() {

    return sass('scss/*.scss', { sourcemap: true })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(minifyCss({}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe( concat("app.min.css"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest( './build' ));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scss-to-css']);
```

Before you run gulp, `gem install sass` is required.

Please refer to the [github example repo](https://github.com/b6pzeusbc54tvhw5jgpyw8pwz2x6gs/examples/tree/master/sassSourceMapInGulp).

Comment: thanks. If you find solution without gem, please, post it.